# Gutenberg Custom Block: Add elements by innerBlocks length

Tags: reactjs, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

**Context**: I'm working on a Custom Gutenberg plugin. One of the blocks I'm trying to create is a Carousel (using Bootstrap's Carousel).

I'm trying to optional add indicators based on the number of child blocks. I'm getting the error:
`Block validation: Block validation failed`

It definitely has something to do with me adding in the indicators. Here's my block. Can anyone help?

```
/**
 * BLOCK: Laboratory Blocks Carousel
 */
import classNames from 'classnames';
import { Fragment } from 'react';
import CarouselOptions, {
  CarouselOptionAttributes,
} from './options';
import heightClass from './classes';

const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks;
const { InspectorControls, InnerBlocks } = wp.editor;
const { select, dispatch } = wp.data;
const { __ } = wp.i18n;
const ALLOWED_BLOCKS = [];

registerBlockType('laboratory-blocks/carousel', {
  title: __('LB Carousel'),
  icon: 'slides',
  category: 'laboratory-blocks',
  description: __('A Bootstrap Carousel'),
  supports: { anchor: true },
  keywords: [
    __('Carousel'),
    __('Slider'),
  ],
  attributes: {
    ...CarouselOptionAttributes,
    test: {
      type: 'object',
    },
    clientId: {
      type: 'string',
      default: 'laboratory-carousel',
    },
  },

  edit(props) {
    const { setAttributes, isSelected } = props;
    const { clientId } = props;
    // find innerBlocks, add "active" to the first slide, set attribute slideLength
    const children = select('core/editor').getBlocksByClientId(clientId)[0].innerBlocks;
    const firstChild = children[0] || false;
    if (firstChild) {
      dispatch('core/editor').updateBlockAttributes(firstChild.clientId, { className: 'active' });
      setAttributes({ clientId });
    }

    return [
      !!isSelected && (
        <InspectorControls key="inspector">
          <CarouselOptions {...props} />
        </InspectorControls>
      ),
      <Fragment>
        <p>Laboratory Blocks Carousel:&nbsp;
          <small>Include a unique ID under &quot;Carousel Options&quot;</small>
        </p>
        <hr />
        <InnerBlocks allowedBlocks={ALLOWED_BLOCKS} />
      </Fragment>,
    ];
  },

  save(props) {
    const { className, attributes, innerBlocks } = props;
    const {
      carouselHeight,
      hasControls,
      hasIndicators,
      interval,
      pauseOnHover,
      carouselId,
    } = attributes;
    const height = heightClass(attributes);
    const classes = classNames(className, 'carousel', 'slide', height);
    const styles = carouselHeight ? { height: carouselHeight } : {};
    const timing = interval || false;
    const hover = pauseOnHover ? 'hover' : false;

    const containerTags = {
      ID: carouselId,
      className: classes,
      style: styles,
      'data-ride': 'carousel',
      'data-interval': timing,
      'data-pause': hover,
    };

    let Indicators;
    if (innerBlocks && 0 < innerBlocks.length) {
      Indicators = innerBlocks.map((block, i) => {
        const c = (0 === i) ? 'active' : '';
        return (
          <li
            key={`${carouselId}-trigger-${block.clientId}`}
            data-target={`#${carouselId}`}
            data-slide-to={i}
            className={c}
          />
        );
      });
    }

    return (
      <div {...containerTags}>
        <InnerBlocks.Content />
        {
          hasControls && (
            <Fragment>
              <a claclassName="carousel-control-prev" href={`#${carouselId}`} role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span className="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true" />
                <span className="sr-only">Previous</span>
              </a>
              <a claclassName="carousel-control-prev" href={`#${carouselId}`} role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span className="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true" />
                <span className="sr-only">Next</span>
              </a>
            </Fragment>
          )
        }
        {
          hasIndicators && (
            <ol className="carousel-indicators">
              {Indicators}
            </ol>
          )
        }
      </div>
    );
  },
});
```

Comment: Kindly share the edit function, as well as the full block code. Otherwise, It'd be hard for people to debug. Make sure your edit function HTML nodes match with your save function HTML nodes.

Comment: @AshiquzzamanKiron Thanks for responding. I just updated my question to include the entire block.

Answer (score 3):

**My solution:**

1. Move the indicators (the dots of the carousel) into a seperate component for code-reuse.
2. Used it in both the edit and save methods.
3. Saved the number of innerBlocks in the edit function and set it as an attribute to be used in the save function.

```

```
registerBlockType('laboratory-blocks/carousel', {...},
    edit: {
      const { clientId } = props;

      ...

      // find number of children and set it as an attribute
      const innerCount = select('core/editor').getBlocksByClientId(clientId)[0].innerBlocks.length;
      setAttributes({ clientId, innerCount });

      return [
        <div>
          ...
          <Indicators count={attributes.innerCount} clientId={clientId} />
        </div>
      ];
    }
    save: {
      const { clientId, attributes } = props;
      const { innerCount } = attributes;
      ...

      return [
        <div>
          ...
          <Indicators count={innerCount} clientId={clientId} />
        </div>
      ];
    }
}
```

```

Comment: Thanks, this was useful for me!